# Check via shell-script if git repository's master branch is behind origin

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, git

I'm currently writing a bash script to remind me to rebase git repos when the local master branch is found to be behind origin/master.

So far I have come up with the following, but `$?` always returns `1` (I suspect this is because even an empty diff still loads `less`.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPO_PATH=$1
cd $REPO_PATH

# flow once inside repo
{
  git fetch
  git diff master origin/master
} &> /dev/null

if [ "" = $? ]
then
  echo "Empty"
  # logic to follow
else
  {
  git pull
  } &> /dev/null
  echo "Don't forget to rebase!!!"
  echo $REPO_PATH
fi

# check for changes to master
# If master is behind origin/master
# then pull master and notify me to rebase

# run this at the start of the day (this script should be run from my start_work
# script and should also be periodically run throughout the day. [maybe every
# time I'm about to run coverage/push?])
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`git-merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)’s `--is-ancestor` test:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/master master; then
    echo Empty
else
    echo "Don't forget to rebase!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking at the exit status, you could look at the actual output

eg

```
git fetch &> /dev/null
diffs=$(git diff master origin/master)

if [ -z "$diffs" ]
then
  echo "Empty"
```

Comment: While this works the results are slightly different than Stephen Kitt's answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503548/188901) using merge-base as his will check if you are behind the master this one will also tell you if you have changes in your local branch (dirty or checked in). I didn't want this so this isn't for me but might be what others want.
Thought I would make the dif clear. :)