# git pre-commit script

Tags: bash, shell-script, git, bash-functions

The goal is to exit from the script with a non-zero exit code when committing `package-lock.json` with no associated changes to `package.json` being committed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences
file_changed() {
  git diff --quiet --exit-code "$1"
}

# exits with 1 if no lines were selected, 0 if one or more lines selected, > 1 if error
file_staged() {
  git diff --name-only --cached | grep -q "$1"
}

# package-lock.json has changed and
#   package-lock.json in staged files and
#   package.json not in staged files?
if [[ file_changed "package-lock.json" -eq 1 &&
  file_staged "package-lock.json" -eq 0 &&
  file_staged "package.json" -eq 1 ]]
then
  echo "attempted commit of package-lock.json without changes to package.json!"
  exit 1
fi
```

I'm fairly certain the problem lies in my `files_staged` function. When testing `file_staged "package-lock.json" -eq 0`, I get the expected results. When testing `file_staged "package.json" -eq 1`, it always fails.

Simplifying the problem, I can never get this condition to trigger when `package.json` is not in the list of files returned by `git diff --name-only --cached`:

```
if file_staged "package.json" -eq 1; then
  echo "got here."
fi
```

Where am I going wrong?

---

**EDIT**

@Jesse_b pointed out that I should be using `$()` around my function calls so that the numerical comparison operators aren't sent as arguments to the function. The following example still doesn't give the desired result:

```
if [[ $(file_staged "package.json") -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "got here."
fi
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Check via shell-script if git repository’s master branch is behind origin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503473/80216).

Answer (score 1):

None of the conditions in your `if` construct work.  Since you aren't using a test command (`test`, `[`, `[[`) you are simply testing the return status of your function.

Example:

```
$ test () { echo 0; }
$ if test -eq 1; then echo yes; fi
0
yes
$ if test -eq 10; then echo yes; fi
0
yes
$ if test -eq 100000000000; then echo yes; fi
0
yes
```

The `-eq ...` is being treated as an option to the `test` function, and that function is returning 0 so it's being treated as a success.

You want to use a test command:

```
if [[ $(file_changed "package-lock.json") -eq 1 &&
  $(file_staged "package-lock.json") -eq 0 &&
  $(file_staged "package.json") -eq 1 ]]
then
  echo "attempted commit of package-lock.json without changes to package.json!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right. By enclosing the function call in `$()`, I'm preventing the `-eq` from being sent as arguments to the function. However, I'm encountering another problem. The `file_staged()` function isn't working as expected. When I run the command from the command line, I get the expected results, but not in my script. I'll update my question accordingly.